# Service workers with non git-committed global variables

Tags: service-worker

In the script below I am hard-coding a firebase variable that I'd rather not commit to my repo. My firebase values are all in a single file and the rest of my javascript imports those using ES6 modules (and webpack). But how should I access that data from this service worker file

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.9.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.9.0/firebase-messaging.js');

// Initialize the Firebase app in the service worker by passing in the config.messagingSenderId.
firebase.initializeApp({
  'messagingSenderId': "8033333334"
});
// firebase.initializeApp({
//   'messagingSenderId': config.messagingSenderId
// });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any scripts that you reference via `importScripts()` will execute synchronously in the same `ServiceWorkerGlobalScope` as your main service worker file. That means that they share the same `self` global, and you know that after the `importScripts()` completes, they will have fully executed.

So if you had a script called `bootstrap.js`, and it contained

```
self.config = self.config || {};
self.config.messagingSenderId = 'my_sender_id';
```

then you could do the following in your `service-worker.js`:

```
importScripts(
  'bootstrap.js',
  'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.9.0/firebase-app.js',
  'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.9.0/firebase-messaging.js'
);

firebase.initializeApp({
  'messagingSenderId': self.config.messagingSenderId
});
```

It's up to you whether you check in `bootstrap.js` to source control, whether you generate it on the fly during build time, etc.

Comment: Thanks, the `export` line in my existing config file caused a problem, so I separated out the data I needed in the sw to another file. A small amount of duplication but definitely a good way forward